# Attribute "A" missing in the zipped file through powershell "Compress-Archive"

Tags: powershell, zip, puppet

Compressed a file through powershell `Compress-Archive` feature.
On opening the archive in the 7-zip there is no 'A' in the attribute column, i believe 'A' stands for archive.

When file compressed through windows feature (`send to -> Compressed (zipped) folder`) "A" attribute is present(When opened archive in 7-zip).

How can I get the 'A' attribute when zipped through `Compress-Archive`?

**Real problem:**

I am trying to unzip the file through puppet.

- unzip working on files zipped through windows feature
- unzip not working on `Compress-Archive` feature (only through puppet, normal `unzip` command is working)

On opening both the zipped files (`through Compress-Archive, windows feature`) in 7-zip archive I observed that attribute 'A' is missing in the zipped (`Compress-Archive`) file.

Please help.

Tagged `puppet` as well, could be a known scenario.

Comment: The Windows "archive" bit has nothing to do with archive files in the sense of the `Compress-Archive` PowerShell command.  Its intended purpose is [to mark files that should be included in a *backup*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_bit), on account of having been created or modified since the last backup.  I see no reason to think that this attribute would impact anyone's ability or inclination to extract zip files.

Comment: There is, indeed, confusion in this question. What is the code you have tried?